# Spring Boot App - Tomcat can't access SQLite database file

Tags: java, spring-boot, sqlite, maven, tomcat

I have been searching about this solution for days now and I can't figure out a solution about it.

I have a Java Spring Boot application supposed to interact with a database, for ease to use and store I chose a SQLite database file. My application is hosted on a Tomcat 8.5 on a Windows Server 2019.

On launch my applications is supposed to read the SQLite database but I'm getting the error : `[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: users_moved_group)`

The error shows that the application cannot find the database but it does exist and I have double check a thousand times the path (I also tried absolute and relative paths), here it is :

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:sqlite:C:/Tomcat 8.5/db/workday.sqlite
```

[image]

As you can see, everything checks out. So my guess is that the Tomcat Service cannot read the file , but it is located inside the Tomcat folder especially to avoid this kind of error (on clean install of a Windows Server and Tomcat it works).

The issue only happens on one of 3 Virtual Machine, not mine but where I still have almost all admin rights.

I am totally lost here, nothing I do makes the Tomcat see the file to allow my application to reads it.

Here is a sample code reading the database :

public void clearTable() {

```
Connection connection;
String usersMovedGroupTable = "users_moved_group";
String sqlExpression = "SELECT * FROM " + usersMovedGroupTable;

List<UsersMovedGroup> usersMovedGroupList = new ArrayList<>();

try {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(applicationProperties.getDatasourceUrl());
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sqlExpression);
    while(rs.next())
    {
        UsersMovedGroup user = new UsersMovedGroup(rs.getString("ump_date"), rs.getString("ump_user_id"), rs.getString("ump_user_login"), rs.getString("ump_group_id"), rs.getString("ump_group_name"));
        usersMovedGroupList.add(user);
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    logger.error("Error connecting to SQLite database : " + e.getMessage());
}
```

At first I was using `jdbcTemplate` to make SQL request but I changed it to `Statement` etc, but same result.

If you want here is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.sqlite</groupId>
  <artifactId>user-moved-ad-group-event-hook</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>user-moved-ad-group-event-hook</name>
  <description>Detect user changed of AD group</description>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SQLite -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
      <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>3.34.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>lyvoc</id>
      <properties>
        <activatedProperties>lyvoc</activatedProperties>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>prod</id>
      <properties>
        <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: Why not test your theory by seeing if you can open a stream on file C:/Tomcat 8.5/db/workday.sqlite before you do anything else.

Comment: _"no such table: users_moved_group"_: I believe this is the reason of the error. The connection to the database should be fine. BTW: your code does not use Spring's datasource, but establishes an independent connection.

Comment: @g00se It seems that `new BufferedReader(new FileReader("linxensworkday.sqlite")` finds my file as logging `buffer.readLine()` gives me this `SQLite format 3   @                                                                     .K�`. So I can't figure why  `connection` won't work. @Piotr P. Karwasz As I said, I was using at the beginning JdbcTemplate whis is using Spring datasource, but same thing happened with less clarity

Comment: Share a link to that database file?

Comment: I would suggest to move the file to a folder inside the classpath.

Comment: @g00se I'm not sure I understood what you meant. @ LMC Inside the WEB-INF/classes ? That's not very clean for deployment

Comment: I mean, let us look at the actual db file if you can

Comment: @g00se Ok this is the file, it's empty and supposed to until some execution is done inside.  http://www.filedropper.com/workday 

But I'm not sure that will help as it can be openned inside other env

Comment: It's OK for me with your file but then there's probably too much differing in my environment. Are you sure your connection string is what you think it it?

Comment: Yes it is, I built the same environment on my own and worked with the string. I thought the Tomcat couldn't catch the sqlite dependency jar due to some permission issue, but it is present inside the exploded .war in Tomcat

Comment: @g00se The weird part is when I remove the `.war` of my project and the only file that can't be deleted (and need the Tomcat to fully stops) is the `sqlite-jdbc.jar` file inside `WEB-INF/lib`. That can't be a coincidence

Comment: Out of interest, what is the value of `applicationProperties.getDatasourceUrl()`?

Comment: `spring.datasource.url = jdbc:sqlite:C:/Tomcat 8.5/db/workday.sqlite` It reaches this value from my `application.properties` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comming back with some feedback. After trying everything I tried a fresh install of a Tomcat 9.0 (instead of common used 8.5) and everything works now without any change from the code.

Answer (score 0):

did you try usersMovedGroupTable = "Schema_Name.DataBase_Name";

Comment: Hi @Akin, Please use the comments section to clarify all your open queries of the posted question. Use the Answers section, if you have any suggestions for the questions.

Comment: @Akin I do not understand your comment, this variable is the name of my table "users_moved_group" contained inside my sqlite database "workday.sqlite"

Comment: @JérémiePoisson  Sometimes sql cant find table  with just  table names  because  there can be multiple tables with same name in different shcemas  then we need to show SQL   which shcema we  need to use   for example        [schema_name].table_name